# Testing a oledbcommandbuilder variable for null

Tags: c#, database

I have an OleDbCommand variable that I want to use to create a commandbuilder if it is null, using my dataadapter. If the variable is not null then a commandbuilder has already been created in this variable. If I make the variable local and test for null it gripes saying: "Use of unassigned local variable..." If I make the variable public/global, everything works. The relevant code is:

```
//Created locally in a button procedure:
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder;

if (cBuilder == null)
{
    cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
}
```

If I comment out the declaration locally and define it as public up with the other public variables, then it works fine without any griping. Relative to what I'm doing, why would its scope being local or public make any difference? I just want to test to see if the commandbuilder has already been created so I don't create multiple ones over and over. I'm doing the same thing with my dataadapter variable but in that case it has to be public anyway. So is there a better way to attack this in general to test to see if something has already been created before trying to create it?

Answer (score 1):

> > Relative to what I'm doing, why would it's scope being local or public make any difference???

The difference is that local variables *have no value* at the start of the method that contains them. It doesn't matter how many times the method has run, its variables will start off with no value every time it is executed.

In your example:

```
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder;

if (cBuilder == null)
{
    cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
}
```

This null check is pointless, because `cBuilder` has no value at this point and there is therefore no reason to check whether it is `null`.

The C# compiler prevents accessing a local variable before it is assigned a value. This is a safeguard to help to weed out bugs.

If you are working with a relatively complicated method with a lot of branching and it becomes too complicated to ensure a variable has a value every step of the way, you can initialize it to `null` (or some other value) when you declare it:

```
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = null;
```

I make a point to avoid doing this except where there is a compelling reason to do so. The compiler's restrictions against accessing uninitialized variables are there for a reason, and the above is usually just a lazy way to circumvent them.

Comment: どうも有難う  JL.... I got caught up in the concept of disposing and was afraid that each time this code was called that it would be creating duplicate objects, in this case the OleDbCommandBuilder. So if the local variables start with no values each time then am I correct in assuming that the objects that they represented are automatically disposed??? If so this is good as it simplifies things.

Comment: They will not necessarily be automatically disposed. You should use a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block to ensure that they are disposed each time you finish using one.